# How can I validate this textfield where it would not allow submission if the entered value is negative?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have this text field type `number`, I want to set a minimum of 0 and a text field that does not accept negative values. I was able to do that, however, once I type on it, I would not be able to delete the `0`, I would first need to go at front of the `0` then type in a number, and only then would the `0` be deleted. What can I do to fix or are there more suitable ways to do this?

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/textfield-7sfdph?file=/demo.js:127-882

Codes:

```
export default function BasicTextFields() {
  const [fee, setFee] = useState(0);
  const amount = parseInt(1000);
  const total = Number(amount) + Number(fee);
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(" submit");
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={{ handleSubmit }}>
      <TextField
        label="Fee"
        type="number"
        value={fee}
        onChange={(e) => {
          if (e.target.value === "") {
            setFee(0);
          } else {
            setFee(parseInt(e.target.value));
          }
        }}
        InputProps={{
          inputProps: {
            min: 0
          }
        }}
      />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      <br />
      Total: {total}
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: Remove `setFee` / `onchange`, set `min` to **0** and add [`required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number). [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#validation) example from the docs is kinda what you need.

Comment: @Lain I can't put a `required` on it because I am using this in a form where this fee is not required.

Comment: Why cant you just leave it empty in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Your `onChange` function is setting the value to `0` whenever the value is an empty string. When you delete something you are effectively changing the value, so the `onChange` function will be called.

Personally I would just call `setFee` with whatever value they typed because the `type=number` will already prevent users from typing anything that is not a number and will allow them to clear the field.

You can handle the case for when the value is empty with validation or on the `onSubmit` function. This is probably a better user experience.

Comment: so I would need to check if `setFee` is not a negative value and then prevent it from submitting?

Answer (score -1):

You can check if number is negative if yes then set value to 0

```js
const total = Number(amount) + (fee ? Number(fee) : 0);
// code 
if (Number(e.target.value) < 0) {
  setFee(0);
} else {
  setFee(parseInt(e.target.value));
}
```

then on submit check if value is not undefined

Comment: Vakhria But it won't let me delete the initial value of 0, I would still need to go at the front of the `0` to and type in a number then delete it

Comment: I have updated answer now it would work